# Flutter difference between TabBar and TabBarView

Tags: flutter

My question is about the difference between `TabBar` and `TabBarView`.
I can't tell any difference in looks, but what are the functions of both of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TabBar` is used to create the tabs themselves, while `TabBarView` is used to create each bar content.

Look at the example in the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: TabBar Demo]

From the image the TabBar is the bottom of the blue bar (AppBar), and the TabBar view is the white page under the bar. Also the whole application is wrapped with `DefaultTabController`

Comment: Ahhhh tank you very much, now I get it :)